# upgrade from ie6 to ie8

Tags: internet-explorer

I'm downloading ie8 for windows xp. Would it be safe to just install this ie8 without uninstalling ie6? Does this method will leave nothing about ie6 on my system. And all of its functions will be replaced by ie8?

Comment: Unless noted or asked to uninstall the old software, a lot of installers keep this in mind when installing so it isn't a problem. You can always choose to remove it yourself first, or install and experiment... Nothing wrong will happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's safe just to install ie8 over the top of ie6.

I did this recently when I reinstalled everything on my old machine and then built my new machine.

Comment: I agree, consider it an update as opposed to a separate program as far as installation goes. DEATH TO IE6!

Answer (score 1):

IE8 effectively replaces IE6. In XP you can't uninstall IE6 really. Just not install it. Once its on there its on there for good. (Unless you want to do some heavy registry hacking.)